# Calculating the size of a box for multiple products for carrier module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, carrier, dimensions, select-size

**Example**: Suppose I have three products like a phone(2w,4h,3d), power bank(12w,15h,8d), screen guard(1.2w,1.8h,1d)

By using these three dimensions to make new Box dimensions. I have to fit these three products using the latest dimensions Box.

W: width, H: height, D:depth

I took the wrong dimensions for just an example to understand the purpose.

Comment: Please help me as soon as possible with code and example.

Comment: I need a basic PHP code or Magento code.